# Ruby on Rails- Time Condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime

I want to compare the current time with submission with Datetime stamp to setup a controller which only shows submission of a specific time. Such as posts done in past hour, day or week.

So I don't get how to access current time. Does it need to be part of database? How can it be defined and how to compare it which post submissions?

Comment: `Time.now`? you can also use `1.day.ago` and etc. if you want to compare, simply use ">"

Comment: What have you tried, what do you receive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add to the earlier answer

For posts this week

```
@posts = Post.where("created_at > ?", Time.now.beginning_of_week)
```

For posts this month:

```
@posts = Post.where("created_at > ?", Time.now.beginning_of_month)
```

Answer (score 0):

From the below query you will get the posts that got created one hours ago.

```
now = Time.now

@posts= Post.where(created_at: (now - 1.hours)..now)
```

To get posts created one week ago

```
@posts = Post.where("created_at > ?", Time.now - 7.days)
```